# Performance wise and fastest way to get all element with Id inside a container element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refactor and make a performance wise code.

The idea of the code is to update the `id` or `value` of all element with `id` or `value` that needs to be updated that happens when an element has been removed / deleted

So what I am trying to do is get all element with `Id` or `value` inside a container element (which is possible to be nested in 2 to 4).

At the moment, I am using `jQuery` to this task. I added a class on every element that has Id and use `jQuery .find()` to get all of this element using the class I've assign to them .. which is I really hate about my code and wanted to change as well if there's another best way to do it.

So is there a fastest way and performance wise at the same time to do this task?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
   $($(this).val()).remove();
   updateParagraph();
});

function updateParagraph() {
   $(".paragraphs").each(function(index, data){
   var dataId = data.id.split("-");
   var idIndex = dataId[dataId.length-1];
   var index = index + 1;
   if (index != idIndex) {
      dataId.splice(-1, 1);
      dataId.push(index);
      dataId = dataId.join("-");
      $(this).attr("id", dataId);
      setChildElementsId($(this), index)
    }
  });
}

function setChildElementsId(parent, inx) {
   $(parent).find(".id-holder").each(function(index, data){
     if (data.id) {
        var dataId = data.id.split("-");
        dataId.splice(-1, 1);
        dataId.push(inx);
        dataId = dataId.join("-");
        $(this).attr("id", dataId);
        if(isParagraph(data.tagName)) {
         $(this).text(inx);
        }
    }
    else if (data.value) {
      var dataValue = data.value.split("-");
      dataValue.splice(-1, 1);
      dataValue.push(inx);
      dataValue = dataValue.join("-");
      $(this).val(dataValue);  
    }
  });
}

function isParagraph(tagName){
 return tagName == "P";
};
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="paragraphs">
  <div id="header-container-id-1" class="id-holder">
    <h4>Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph-container-id-1" class="id-holder">
    <p id="id-1" class="id-holder">1</p>
  </div>
  <button value="#container-1" class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
<div id="container-2" class="paragraphs">
  <div id="header-container-id-2" class="id-holder">
    <h4>Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph-container-id-2" class="id-holder">
    <p id="id-2" class="id-holder">2</p>
  </div>
  <button value="#container-2" class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
<div id="container-3" class="paragraphs">
  <div id="header-container-id-3" class="id-holder">
    <h4>Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph-container-id-3" class="id-holder">
    <p id="id-3" class="id-holder">3</p>
  </div>
  <button value="#container-3" class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
<div id="container-4" class="paragraphs">
  <div id="header-container-id-4" class="id-holder">
    <h4>Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph-container-id-4" class="id-holder">
    <p id="id-4" class="id-holder">4</p>
  </div>
  <button value="#container-4" class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
<div id="container-5" class="paragraphs">
  <div id="header-container-id-5" class="id-holder">
    <h4>Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph-container-id-5" class="id-holder">
    <p id="id-5" class="id-holder">5</p>
  </div>
  <button value="#container-5" class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've answered your question using plain javascript. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to more elegantly identify which elements have an `id` of the form "__-id-#" or simply "id-#".

If this is the case, take a look at some [more advanced jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). One in particular which might meet your needs is the [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

For instance, I think `$(parent).find("[id*='id-']")` might do what you're looking to do.

Comment: You are correct and I got your idea as well. but the thing is that the id are dynamically created which the only thing I know is they are in sequence (I mean they have numbers in their i.d e.g., my-id-1, my-another-id-2). If i need to do this trick I should know their individual i.d right?

Answer (score 0):

While I understand *what* you're attempting to do, I don't quite understand *why* you're doing this in the first place.

Unless there are restrictions that *force* you to structure your HTML like you did, well, don't. Aim for the simplest structure:

```
<div id="container-123" class="paragraphs">
  <h4>Header</h4>
  <p>1</p>
  <button type="button">delete</button>
</div>
```

Remove the `<div>`s around the `<h4>` and the `<p>` unless you need them for some styling reason. The `<button>` doesn't need to know its ID, because it's a child element of the container, so you're delete handler could make use of that fact:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).closest('.paragraphs').remove();
});
```

If there are outside forces that require a specific ID (e.g. for linking to an anchor), keep that on the top container element. If your CSS targets elements by ID, refactor the CSS.

Comment: **unless you need them for some styling reason** yeah I need them for some styling reason and this element are being generated dynamically..the structure of the markups are just an example.. In the real page the markups will be in input groups which is pretty similar into bootstrap that is why this div will be required :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question using javascript. In fact you don't need any of those `id`-s

I hope I'm not too late.

```js
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".id-holder"));

buttons.forEach(b => {
//for each button add an event listener
  b.addEventListener("click", () => {
    b.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(b.parentElement);
    resetNums();
  });
});


function resetNums(){
// reseting the text inside the p
  let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".id-holder"));
  btns.forEach((bt,i)=>{
    let theP = bt.parentElement.querySelector("p");
    theP.innerHTML = i+1;
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Header1</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <button class="id-holder">delete</button> 
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Header2</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <button class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Header3</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <button class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Header4</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
  <button class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Header5</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <button class="id-holder">delete</button>
</div>
```